# Запуск функции с помощью setInterval

Tags: javascript, animate, setinterval

Столкнулся с необходимостью "слайдерить" фон сайта, который очень широкий по размеру.

```
function changeBg() {
    $(document.body).animate({ 'backgroundpositionX': '50%' }, 1000);
    console.log("!");
}               
setInterval(changeBg(), 3000)
```

Тут не идет никакой речи о постоянном "слайдеринге" (так как значение у фона будет `50%`), но почему данный пример срабатывает один раз?

То есть, по идее, я должен получать в консоли сообщения из `console.log` каждые 3 секунды. Я пробовал создавать переменную, которая бы меняла значение с каждой итерацией, но функция срабатывает один раз всегда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в строке `setInterval(changeBg(), 3000)`.

Что в ней происходит: отрабатывает функция `changeBg`, после чего результат её работы (`undefined`) подставляется в качестве первого параметра в `setInterval()`.

Правильно делать так:

```js
function changeBg() {
  $(document.body).animate({ 'backgroundpositionX': '50%' }, 1000);
  console.log("!");
}
setInterval(changeBg, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: И тем не менее функция отрабатывает один раз

Comment: @Колюня я добавил в ответ полный пример кода. В нём вы можете убедиться, что в консоли сообщение появляется каждые 3 секунды.

Comment: Спасибо большое, возможно у меня просто версия jquery была 1.6, но да - убедился работает.

Comment: @Колюня на здоровье. Не забудьте в таком случае отметить ответ как правильный. По поводу jQuery - `.animate()` был добавлен в версии 1.0, так что конкретно в этом месте вряд ли проблема. Но версия `1.6` очень старая, скажем прямо.